# Adding 1 to div onsubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a form that i submit to a database using ajax, there a div on the page which has a database binding which counts the total number of records submit on page refresh. now what i want to do is onsubmit of the form, i should add 1 to the binding in the div which counts the total number of records submitted

```
<div id="count_div"></div>
    <form id="form2" name="form2" method="POST" action="<%=MM_editAction%>">
              <input name="comment" type="text" id="comment" size="50" />
              <input name="imageField3" type="image" id="imageField3" src="imgs/buttons/comment.png" align="bottom" />
              <input name="wardrobe" type="hidden" id="wardrobe" value="1" />
              <input name="comme" type="hidden" id="comme" value="2" />
              <input name="comfn" type="hidden" id="comfn" value="3" />
              <input name="photo_id" type="hidden" id="photo_id" value="4" />
              <input name="ctype" type="hidden" id="ctype" value="picture" />
              <input name="resp_email" type="hidden" id="resp_email" value="4" />
              <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form2" />
            </form>
```

AJAX

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form2").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "int_p_cmt.asp",
        data: data
        }).success(function() {

 $("#msg_div").append("<div class='messages' style='border:1px purple solid; padding:2px; margin:5px;'>Your comment has been saved </div>");

            setTimeout(function() { 
                $(".messages").fadeOut(function(){
                    $(".messages").remove();
                }); 
            }, 1000);

            $("input[type=text]").val("");

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: And what have you tried already?

Comment: this is what i have and it submits perfectly to the database and i'm new to jquery, so i'm finding it hard to do

Comment: `$("#count_div").text('20');`?

Comment: what? i don't get what you are trying to say

Comment: which div counts the numbers?

Comment: oh I got it `#count_div`!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form2").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "int_p_cmt.asp",
        data: data
        }).success(function() {
            window.counter=parseInt($('#count_div').html());
            window.counter++;
            $('#count_div').html(window.counter);
            $("#msg_div").append("<div class='messages' style='border:1px purple solid; padding:2px; margin:5px;'>Your comment has been saved </div>");

            setTimeout(function() { 
                $(".messages").fadeOut(function(){
                    $(".messages").remove();
                }); 
            }, 1000);

            $("input[type=text]").val("");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: when i click on submit instead of adding up what what is there, it clears it and starts counting from 1 and upwards.

Comment: you mean you don't want it to start counting from 0? if not what number? and is there any code inside the `#count_div`?

Comment: yeah, it has the total number of records submit to the database

Comment: so you're saying that there is a number in the `#count_div` before you click on submit, if so, then check the answer again, I updated it

Comment: when i click on submit, the content in the div disaapears and comes back again with i refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

if what I understood is correct: you want to increment th value of the "count_div" div then try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form2").on('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "int_p_cmt.asp",
    data: data
    }).success(function() {

        $("#msg_div").append("<div class='messages' style='border:1px purple solid; padding:2px; margin:5px;'>Your comment has been saved </div>");

        setTimeout(function() { 
            $(".messages").fadeOut(function(){
                $(".messages").remove();
            }); 
        }, 1000);

        $("#count_div").html(parseFloat($("#count_div").html())+1);

        $("input[type=text]").val("");

    });
});
```

});

Comment: when i click on submit the content in the div disappears

Comment: and what was the div containing before you click on submit?

Comment: it contains the total number of records already submitted which i call from the database. it only refreshes when i refresh the page, but this time i want it to refresh when i click on the submit button

Comment: if you have that on a link that could help a lot

Comment: you mean the value in the div?

Comment: I mean if you can send me a link to the page containing this code this can help a lot